# sed: replace a line containing a pattern

Tags: regex, shell, sed, replace

I saw so much questions about the `sed` command but none match my dude.

I want to substitute the entire line which contains a pattern.

I think the `sed` command is the best option. I started with this `sed` command but doesn't work

```
sed -i 's/pattern/Substitution/' myfile.txt
```

After that i'm testing with this other command but only substitute the pattern, not the entire line.

```
echo "hello y luego bye" | sed "s|hello|adeu|g"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to match the whole line containing that pattern and then replace. Use it like this:

```
sed 's/^.*\bpattern\b.*$/Substitution/' file
```

I also added `\b` for word boundaries so that you only match `pattern` but avoid matching `patterns`.

**Explanation:** `^.*\bpattern\b.*$` us used to make sure whole line is matched containing pattern. `^` is line start and `$` is line end. `.*` matches 0 or more length text. So `^.*` matches all the text before `pattern` and `.*$` matches all the text after `pattern`.

Using awk you can do:

```
awk '!/affraid/{print} /affraid/{print "Substitution"}' file
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. But can you explain whats the meaning of '^.*' before the pattern and '.*$' after it ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And i don't understand your explanation for \b, cause without \b works nice.

Comment: `\b` is used for word boundaries. With `\b` match string will be: `^.*pattern.*$` and it can also match a line eg: `123 mypatterns foo` but when I used `^.*\bpattern\b.*$` it won't match that line.