# Sed command for replace line in Unix

Tags: sed, pattern-matching, ksh, aix

I'm trying to adapt an script to make it work in an aix server. The scripts must replace a line which contains a pattern with other line with the same pattern but adding more info.
Following my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342674/sed-replace-a-line-containing-a-pattern):

I want to replace the line which contain the pattern `CASIOPEA_STORE_BDD_PWD`, here the code which still doesn't work :

```
sed -i 's/^.*\bCASIOPEA_STORE_BDD_PWD\b.*$/CASIOPEA_STORE_BDD_PWD='MyCasioPass2014#'/g' casiopeia.conf
```

Now i'm trying the script on OS X and this command throws me the following error message:

```
sed: 1: "File's route ...": invalid command code m
```

**Q2:** Is it possible to add this line to the file `casiopeia.conf` if it isn't exists in the file ?

Comment: why do you have `'MyCasioPass2014'`? Do you really want single-quotes to surround that text? If so, try `sed "s/.....\$/'...'/g" ....` Good luck.

Comment: the `\b` word anchors might not be portable. You might try `\<word\>`

Comment: I also think the -i option is a GNU extension to the sed command and doesnt work on AIX.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think in place editing (-i) flag of sed works on AIX:

You could try:

```
sed "s/^.*\bCASIOPEA_STORE_BDD_PWD\b.*$/CASIOPEA_STORE_BDD_PWD=\'MyCasioPass2014\'/g" casiopeia.conf >casiopeia.edit
```

Or install the GNU version of sed on AIX

For Q2:

```
#!/bin/ksh

search="CASIOPEA_STORE_BDD_PWD"
replace="CASIOPEA_STORE_BDD_PWD=\'MyCasioPass2014\'"
filename="$1"

#Grep for search pattern
grep q "$search" "$filename"
if [ $? -ne -0 ]; then
    #Match not found, append line   
    echo "$search" >> "$filename"
else
    #Match found, create tmp file for inplace editing
    tmpfile=$(mktemp "/tmp/$filename.XXXXX")
    #Copy orignal to tmpfile
    cat $filename >$tmpfile
    #Sed line non-case sensitive
    sed "s/^.*$search.*$/$replace/g" "$tmpfile" >"$filename"
    #Remove temp file
    rm "$tmpfile"
fi
```

Comment: I tried your command, but i doesn't make any modification in the target file. But throws no errors at execution time. I tried deleting the b delimeter or changing the " surrounding the options by single quoutes but also doesn't work. Is there any option to not only substitute the word marked into \b and replace all the line containing the pattern ?

Comment: I don't have access to an AIX box unfortunately but it might also be that the **i** (case insensitive) is a GNU sed flag. Can you try using `sed "s/^.*$search.*$/$replace/g" "$tmpfile" >"$filename"`